# Error in table(x, y) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

Tags: r, plot, read.table

I have a problem with plotting my results. Previously (about two weeks ago) I can use same code at below to plot my data but now I'am getting error

```
data<- read.table("my_step.odt", header = FALSE, sep = "", quote="\"'", dec=".", as.is =  FALSE, strip.white=FALSE, col.names=c(.......); 
mgn_my <- data[1:49999,18]
sim  <- data[1:49999, 21]
plot(sim , mgn_my , type="l",xlab="Time (ns)",ylab="mx")
```

error

```
Error in table(x, y) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Did the `plot` command cause the error or did you call `table` on some of your variables?

Comment: Dear @josilber `plot` command caused it!

Comment: Would you please provide a reproducible example, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You should reduce your data size in any case.  A plot of all 50  thousand points (or generating a line from same) will be indistinguishable from plotting every hundredth point.   That said, there is clearly something wrong with either your dataset, or you have a typo and called the wrong object.  `R` can easily plot 500k points.   Or, possibly, you've overloaded `plot` somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a similar problem as you before. Based on my response from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720814/why-do-i-get-an-error-of-cant-make-a-table-of-more-231-elements-in-r), here's what I would suggest before you run `plot`:

Option 1: Use `droplevels`

```
mgn_my <- droplevels(data[1:49999,18])
```

Option 2: Use `apply`. This approach seems "friendlier" if you are familiar with `apply`-family functions in R. For example:

```
mgn_my <- data[1:49999,18]
apply(mgn_my,1,plot)
```