# Why do I get an error of can't make a table of more 2^31 elements in R

Tags: r

Hello I have a dataframe *record* in R of dimension  8 obs 60 variables , with the missing values replaced by NA and the other values being words.

When I try to tabulate the dataframe like this `feeds<-table(record)` I get an error saying :

```
Error in table(record) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

Some sample elements/structure of my dataframe are

```
INC - CORP Application Issue    INC - CORP Issue    INC - PC Software Issue
Affected User                   Affected User       Affected User
Attachment                      Attachment          Attachment
Description / Priority          Business Critica..  Configuration Item
Knowledge Search                Client ID           Contact Info
NA                              Description / Pr..  NA
```

I don't understand the error as the elements in the dataframe are clearly not even close to 2^31.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try `table(data.frame(a=1:3, b=letters[1:3], c=LETTERS[1:3]))` to see what's going on.

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* why you getting the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its old topic but it might help someone else that reason I posting it.
I had the same problem and I found it online solution from somewhere I don't remember and  it worked for me perfectly. 
hopefully works for someone who needs.

```
solution<-as.data.frame(table(unlist(record)))
```

Comment: Can you please format the code with the code formatting tool?

Comment: And maybe explain what this does and how it's different from `table(record)`. With that addition, it would be a very good answer!

Comment: you could also do solution<-matrix(table(record)) the thing is I had a error which is Error in table(record) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements, my first solution solve the error there is not much difference as long as you don't get the error.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code is trying to make a 60-dimensional table, returning the counts of every unique combination of the 60 variables.  Thus the *> 2^31 elements* error.

Do you want `sapply(record, table)` to tabulate each variable individually?

Comment: Not sure if I am following you, I want to make the data frame as table as how it shows in the View(dataframe)

I tried saapply ,seems like it gives me an list which doesn't look ordered into rows and colums

Comment: Can you expand your example data to show column names and include an example of what your desired result would look like?  I'm unclear on what you want.  The `sapply` command should give you a list of tables, one for each of your variables, with the frequencies of values of that variable.

Comment: The top row in the example are the column names,
I think the table method doesn't like NA in the dataframe and it takes it as Null 

I just want to transform the dataframe into table as it is

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the complicating levels in your data frame. There are two ways to get around this problem:

1. invoke `droplevels` after subsetting the data.frame. For example:

   feeds <- droplevels(record)
2. Use `apply` family functions, like `sapply` someone mentioned earlier. For example:

   feeds <- apply(record,1,table) # output stored as an object
   feeds

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. What worked for me was removing the NA's like this

```
df <- df[!is.na(df)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. What worked for me was by converting each column in the dataframe into a numeric or character using the following lines:

```
df$x = as.numeric(as.character(df$x))
df$y = as.numeric(as.character(df$y))
df$z= as.numeric(as.character(df$z))
```

This will remove the factor levels in each of the variables within the dataframe. If you need the factor levels, I would not recommend doing this, but if you just need the raw values this will work well.